# CakePHP restful API routing to a set of controllers

Tags: php, api, rest, cakephp, routes

I'm wondering if it's possible to set a route in `Cakephp` that will allow me to route to a set of controllers where a prefix is set. What I'm looking to do is duplicate most of my controllers but for a REST api.

I'd like to still have all the default controllers for the site itself but have a product controller for instance that only returns `JSON`. For this I would like to move all api controllers into a subfolder and route to them by detecting `/api/controllername`.

Is this possible or even the correct way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I'm looking to do is duplicate most of my controllers but for a
>   REST api.

Bad idea. IMHO. You're going to duplicate code very likely and scatter code everywhere. Keep it in one place. This sentence is an indicator that makes me think you have to much logic in your controllers. Move it to models, fat models.

There are several better ways to do this.

- Use a prefix for routing to API methods inside your related controllers (api/v1/foo/bar -> ControllerName::api_actionName())
- Implement a single API controller that dispatches model methods (api/v1/foo/bar -> FooModel::barMethod($queryParam1, $queryparam2,...)
- Implement a service layer that sits between the model and the controllers and implement a dispatcher filter or the API controller from the 2nd suggestion to dispatch the service methods. You'll use services instead of models then. Controller <-> Service <-> Model. To implement this well some experience with the framework and design patterns is required. If its not well done  it will probably cause more problems than benefit - IMHO.
- If it's a more or less simple API and the API logic is similar to your actions you can simple re-use the same controller actions you already have and just usethe [built in REST and JSON/XML view](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html) serialization and could still use routing to create a fancy route (api/v1/...) for them. You can then do conditional checks as well if the controller is called as API.

It's up to you which one you pick, I've seen and used them all in action, they all work the difference is mostly the implementation and level of abstraction you need. However, the key point is to write clean and DRY code and care about [SoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).